# foreachRDD in Spark Stream will not write file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is my Spark Streaming job:

```
object StreamingTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamingTest")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
        ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
        val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(
                        ssc,
                        "localhost:2181/kafka",
                        "streaming-group",
                        Map("streaming-topic" -> 1),
                        StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
        ).map(_.2)
        lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(token => s"${token} => ${token.hashCode}")
            .foreachRDD(rdd => {
                rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"/results/raw-${System.currentTimeInMillis()}.txt")
            })
        lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(token => s"${token} => ${token.hashCode}")
            .saveAsTextFiles("/results/raw", "test")
        ssc.start
        ssc.awaitTermination
    }
}
```

The last save operation works. It writes files to `/results/raw`. The one inside the foreach loop does not. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Do you have both DAGs (`lines.flatMap...`) inside one application? Or you just enable one of them?

Comment: Same issue on Databricks